# calculate div width in percentage from time duration

Tags: php, html, math, calculator

I am trying to calculate div width based on-time duration in percentage

I have three div give them width and fill background color base on time duration between two dates

```
lengthdiv1=2018-4-01 22:31:59 - 2018-01-01 00:00:00
lengthdiv2=2018-10-10 22:31:59 - 2018-4-01 22:31:59
lengthdiv3=2018-12-31 23:59:59 - 2018-10-10 22:31:59

 $maxWidth = 100; // total percentage 
$eventStart = strtotime('2018-01-01 00:00:00');
$eventEnd   = strtotime('2018-4-01 22:31:59');
$eventLength = $eventEnd - $eventStart;
$maxLength = 86400;
$ratio = $eventLength / $maxLength; 
$width = round($ratio * $maxWidth);
```

HTML code where I'm tried to apply div width in percentage

```
 <div class="daylight">
    <div class="daytime standard" style="width: 20%; background: #D1F1AD;border-left: none;">3m 23d h4</div>
    <div class="daytime summer" style="width: 60%; background: #FDE492; text-align: center">3m 23d h4</div>
    <div class="daytime standard1" style=" background: #D1F1AD;width: 20%; ">3m 23d h4</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the needful.

```
<?php
    $dur1 = (strtotime("2018-04-01 22:31:59")) - (strtotime("2018-01-01 00:00:00"));
    $dur2 = (strtotime("2018-10-10 22:31:59")) - (strtotime("2018-4-01 22:31:59"));
    $dur3 = (strtotime("2018-12-31 23:59:59")) - (strtotime("2018-10-10 22:31:59"));

    $totDur = $dur1 + $dur2 + $dur3;

    $wid1 = round($dur1 * 100 / $totDur);
    $wid2 = round($dur2 * 100 / $totDur);
    $wid3 = round($dur3 * 100 / $totDur);

    echo $wid1, " ", $wid2, " ", $wid3;
```

The strategy here is that

1. Convert the given string into a timestamp in seconds (since [epoch timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) using php's [`int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).
2. Get the difference in seconds.
3. Find the total difference.
4. Convert `each difference / total difference` to percentages and [round](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) it to the nearest integer.

Comment: when I round width nearest value  some time may be width increase from 100% and div layout broken

Comment: Of course if that is the case, you could replace `$wid3 = round($dur3 * 100 / $totDur);` with `$wid3 = 100 - ($wid1 + $wid2);`. It will always ensure that, the total of widths won't exceed 100. Yes there is a problem of precision, but since this is for viewing purposes, I don't think that it is something to be taken into consideration.